# why is colinearity not an issue with linear modeling using the hashing trick (ie vw, fasttext)?

Tags: regression, logistic, linear-model, multicollinearity

Usually when I use linear models I have to do feature selection or use pca to prevent the detrimental effects of collinearity.

I am wondering why algorithms using linear models with the hashing trick don't suffer from this problem?

Is it something to do with the nature of the problems these models are used for? (i.e. I often see these used for text or highly sparse categorical features such as ip addresses).

Comment: Generally when using hashing, the user is interested in prediction and not inference (hashing would defeat any attempt at inference).  Correlation is not an issue in models used for prediction.